# Different values for pseudo R-Squared

Tags: r, regression, cross-validation, r-squared

I have a model:

```
StepHome <- glm(formula = FTHG ~ HS + HST + AST + HF + AF + HC + AC + HY + AY + HR + 
                                 AR + HS:HST + HST:AF + AST:HY + HF:HR + AC:HR + 
                                 HY:HR + HR:AR, family = poisson, data = Data)
```

That I calculated a pseudo R-squared value for from:

```
    Null deviance: 1452.76  on 1139  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  968.72  on 1121  degrees of freedom
AIC: 3158.9

StepHomeR <- 1-(968.72/1452.76)
0.3331865
```

After this I cross-validated the model using the following process:

```
shrinkage <- function(fit, k=10){
  require(bootstrap)

  theta.fit <- function(x,y){lsfit(x,y)}
  theta.predict <- function(fit,x){cbind(1,x)%*%fit$coef}

  x <- fit$model[,2:ncol(fit$model)]
  y <- fit$model[,1]

  results <- crossval(x, y, theta.fit, theta.predict, ngroup=k)
  r2 <- cor(y, fit$fitted.values)^2
  r2cv <- cor(y, results$cv.fit)^2
  cat("Original R-Squared =", r2, "\n")
  cat(k, "Fold Cross-Validated R-Sqaure =", r2cv, "\n")
  cat("Change =", r2-r2cv, "\n")
}

shrinkage(StepHome)
```

Giving the following result:

```
Original R-Squared = 0.4011235 
10 Fold Cross-Validated R-Sqaure = 0.3508091 
Change = 0.05031446
```

I understand that the pseudo R-Squared value is calculated differently in my Cross-Validation code. What I am unsure about:

1. Is the pseudo R-Squared value calculated in the shrinkage() function valid for a generalised linear model?
2. If it is not, could the percentage change still have some use in assessing the model?